# css animation - zooming element from its position to center

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations, zooming

This is an example of the effect I want:
http://photoswipe.com/
The same effect is used for image zooming on WhatsApp web.

I want to zoom elements (not just images) to the center, with an animation scaling element from its position to the center of the page.
The animation should be css based, JS should not be used for animation purposes.

I've tried the following code, which doesn't do the job:

```
<div></div>
```

With the css:

```
div {
  width: 100px; height: 100px; background: blue;
transition: transform 1s
}

div:hover {
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

And, what's the difference between animating transform: scale or width/height?

Thanks

EDIT:
Another attempt:
http://jsfiddle.net/4w06Lvms/

Answer (score -1):

I have made something similar to what you want (view in full screen). You can modify it as per needs. Move pointer out of the screen to get back to original state.

Also, animating using scale is better as you might not know the exact height and width in pixels if there are multiple images and using the same scale value gives your code uniformity.
Hope it helps.

```css
html,body{
  margin:0;
}

.container{
  background:yellow;
  display:flex;
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  justify-content:center;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  vertical-align:center;
}
.imageHover{
  display:flex;
  height:300px;
  width:200px;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}
img{
  position:absolute;
  height:300px;
  width:200px;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}
.container:hover > .imageHover{
  height:100vh;
  background-color:black;
  width:100vw;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}
.container:hover > .imageHover > img{
  transform:translate(240%,50%) scale(1.6);
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="imageHover">
  <img  id="yo" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300
" alt="">
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What if I dont have a fixed height for my element? My elements are inside a bootstrap grid

Comment: That's better.. I've used fixed sizes since I knew the dimensions. The img is in a div with class imageHover which expands to full screen (the black background) . So the size of the image does not matter.

Comment: Kindly mark as selected answer so that it helps others too.

Comment: I've tried your translate() with my example, and the problem is, that not every element is actually centered. See my attempt here: http://jsfiddle.net/4w06Lvms/. So using translate(240%, 50%) does not work for every element (it does not bring the element to the center)

Comment: You can't do it with bootstrap grid as the elements parent has to be a full screen    http://jsfiddle.net/supercoder123/qu5e6b19/ i tried my best here. It's not perfect but i hope it helps

Comment: So if I do use some JS, how can I calculate the the correct translate() so the element moves from its position to the center?